# Abstract Algebra: Order of Elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The question is: Compute the order of elements
(1) $-1,i,\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$ in $G=\mathbb{C^*}$
(2) $4,5,8$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$

For (2), I think I can handle it easily.
For $4$, 4+4=8, 4+4+4=12(0), so order is 3.
Similar approach gives order of $5$ is 12 and order of $8$ is 3.

But for (1), I don't understand why this time it is not using "+" as the operator.

For $-1$, $(-1)^2=1$, $(-1)^3=-1$, so order is 3.

For $i$, order is 4

For $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$, order is 6.

The above two sets of questions are asking the order. But one use "$\times$" and the other use $+$. Is it due to the different group? In (1), elements are in $\mathbb{C^*}$, the * implies the multiplication; while in (2) it is $\mathbb{Z_{12}}$, which is an addition. Can anyone help me to clarify the concept behind? Those answers are done myself after knowing the operations.

Comment: Yes, that is precisely right.  When we want to be totally unambiguous, when we refer to a group we do it as $G=(X,*)$ where $X$ is the set of elements and $*$ is the group operation.  We should have if we wanted to be unambiguous say $(\Bbb C^*,\times)$ and $(\Bbb Z_{12},+)$.  The author of the question assumed that you were already well familiar with these two groups and well familiar that the group operations were multiplication and addition respectively and so decided for whatever reason not to include them.

Comment: Note that since $\mathbb C^*$ does not include $0$, the group operation can't be ordinary addition (there would be no additive identity!). You should turn to ordinary multiplication as the alternative, and realize that $1$ is the (multiplicative) identity.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that $(\Bbb C,+)$ is also a group and every element is of infinite order.  The star above $\Bbb C^*$ implies that we are referring to $\Bbb C\setminus \{0\}$, the set of nonzero complex numbers, which since $0$ is the additive identity implies that we could not have been using addition as the group operation (*as the identity for the operation must be included as an element in the group*)

Comment: As for the order of $-1$ and $i$ in $(\Bbb C^*,\times)$, we are repeatedly applying the group operation *until we reach the identity element*.  $(-1)^1=-1,(-1)^2=1$ and $1$ is the multiplicative identity.  The order is then $2$, not $3$.  $i=i, i^2=-1, i^3=-i, i^4=1$, the order of $i$ is indeed $4$.  You seem to have made that mistake only once.

Comment: Oh, I have spotted out the careless mistakes... Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{C}^*$ is the group of nonzero complex numbers, which is a group under multiplication (note that it is not a group under addition, since for example $1+(-1)=0\notin\mathbb{C}^*$).

Answer (score 0):

For any field $\mathbb F$, you can consider the multiplicative group of nonzero elements, denoted $\mathbb F^*$.  The multiplication symbol is suggestive,  as, by the definition of a field, this is an abelian group...